# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: truncated \uXXXX escape

Tags: python, unicode

I'm completely new to Python and even programming and also this forum. So I just was testing some new stuff that I have learned with Python like printing statements but I get this error:

**SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: truncated \uXXXX escape**

Basically I just wrote this code:

```
print('C\users\desktop')
```

So what's going on there??

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Use \\ instead of \ as the syntax \uXXXX defines a unicode escape code whereas \\ escapes the escape code and lets you use it just fine.

Comment: Try writing `print('C\\users\\desktop')`. Use double slash.

Comment: use raw strings prefix `r"C:\users\desktop"`

Comment: @thaeslocrauo: what is your python version? it's important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests, `\u` is being interpreted as an escape.  In Python 3, you can avoid this by using a raw string:

```
>>> print(r'C\users\desktop')
C\users\desktop
```

Unfortunately, in Python 2 `\u` escapes are still interpreted inside raw (unicode) strings, so you have to do something else.  One possibility is to use bytestrings (i.e., not unicode).  One possibility is to do `'C\\users\\desktop'`.  Another is to do something like `'C\\' r'users\desktop'` (using string concatenation by juxtaposition).  I have encountered this issue myself with Python 2 and, personally, since 99% of the problem is with the `Users` directory on Windows, I just [created a directory junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point#Creating_or_deleting_a_junction_point) that aliases `C:\TheUsers` to `C:\Users`.  Then I can do `r"C:\TheUsers"` with no problems.

Comment: in python 2, it works (\u isn't anything special).OP is probably using python 3. `>>> "c:\users"
 => 'c:\\users'`. using python 2.7.12 here.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: `\u` is indeed a recognized escape in Python 2.  See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: ok, then it doesnt work. Have you tested my example above? I know for sure that people have codes that worked with `\U` in python 2 and broke in python 3. it's in the doc, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I don't know what you're talking about.  Unicode escapes work fine in Python 2.  In fact they work all too well, because in the situation described in this question, there's no way to turn them off.

Comment: you seem to have some bad experience about that so I believe you, but on my windows box python 2.7.12 it just has no effect, like `\c`. which version are you using? maybe they "fixed" in on newer 2.7 releases

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Ah, I see the confusion.  `\u` only works in *unicode* strings in Python 2.  I always use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` so this didn't occur to me.